# Variable '${username1}' not found Variable using Robot Framework with DataDriver library

Tags: robotframework

I'm new in Robot Framework, and now get stuck while using DataDriver library in my robot script.

My problem: There is a message : "Variable '${username1}' not found." while I run the robot script and the test was FAIL.

***My script:***

```
*** Test Cases ***
Login with user ${username} and password ${password}        xyc     123456



*** Keywords ***
Validate Unsuccessful Login
    [Arguments]     ${username1}        ${password1}
    open the browser with the Mortgage payment url
    Fill the login Form     ${username1}        ${password1}
    wait until it checks and display error message
    verify error message is correct
Fill the login Form
    [Arguments]         ${username1}        ${password1}
    input text          id:username          ${username1}
    input password      id:password          ${password1}
    select checkbox     id:terms
    click button        signInBtn
```

***Error:***

```
testDemo5 :: To validate the login form                                       
==============================================================================
Invalidusername,nina,learning                                         | FAIL |
Variable '${username1}' not found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Invalidpassword,rahulshetty,nina                                      | FAIL |
Variable '${username1}' not found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Specialcharacter,@#$##,uqyuyw                                         | FAIL |
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is this the full script? Do you have a *** Settings *** section with Template?

Comment: yes: ** Settings ***
Documentation       To validate the login form
Library             SeleniumLibrary
Library             Collections
Library             DataDriver      file=Resources/data.csv
Test Template       Validate Unsuccessful Login
Test Teardown       close browser

Comment: I've played around and can reproduce error if the CSV file is not exactly like the examples in docs e.g. there cannot be any space between the column names and has to be semi colons not commas. What does your csv file look like?

Comment: Oh and it needs to be ${username} in the arguments, not ${username1}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `Variable '${username1}' not found.` could be caused by one or more of the following reasons:

1. The CSV file uses commas in the header instead of semi colons
2. There are spaces in the CSV headers
3. The arguments within the template keyword don't match up with the embedded variables in the test case.

It looks like issue 3 is definately the case in your code so you would need to change your `Validate Unsuccessful Login` to the following:

```
Validate Unsuccessful Login
    [Arguments]     ${username}        ${password}
    open the browser with the Mortgage payment url
    Fill the login Form     ${username}        ${password}
    wait until it checks and display error message
    verify error message is correct
```

Then inspect your csv file

This style is valid:

```
*** Test Cases ***;${username};${password};[Tags];[Documentation]
```

This style causes the error:

```
*** Test Cases ***,${username},${password},[Tags],[Documentation]
```

And this also cause the error:

```
*** Test Cases ***; ${username}; ${password}; [Tags]; [Documentation]
```